# How can i display only selected options in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am trying to modify the option in Thymeleaf so that the table can show me only selected item, after clicking the option. Here is my code:

```html
 <th>
 <select th:onchange="???" id="stateSelect" class="form-control" th:field="*{receiverType}">
       <option th:value='NULL'>All aggregators</option>
       <option th:each="receiverType : ${receiverTypes}"
               th:value="${receiverType}"
               th:text="${receiverType}">
       </option>
    </select>
</th>
```

I know that i should use `onchange` , but i am confused.

Comment: I think, if you use `onChange` then you have to use JavaScript to toggle/control the `<options>` list. Thymeleaf can do this only if you re-render the HTML via server for every `Change` that is responsible for affecting the `<options>` list.

In short, `onChange` looks useless to me, if not rendering via server.

Comment: So for example which JS function should i use?

Comment: That depends on what condition you want to filter the list. And its way of handling in pure JS is quite dirty too.